# wxPython: Ensure only one instance of a panel is open

Tags: python, wxpython, instance, frame, wxwidgets

I'm writing a multi-window, multi-frame application. For every new window/frame that is opened, there should be one and only one instance of that window. I want the user to be able to quickly switch between these windows, so `ShowModal()` does not work. I've tried using `SingleInstanceChecker`, but I can't get it to work as it's more for Apps than for frames. How should I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit of Google-Fu and found this old thread:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/VTPpXYZYHmM

Using that as my template, I put together this little script and it appears to work on my Linux box:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)


########################################################################
class SingleInstanceFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    instance = None
    init = 0

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __new__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """"""
        if self.instance is None:
            self.instance = wx.Frame.__new__(self)
        elif isinstance(self.instance, wx._core._wxPyDeadObject):
            self.instance = wx.Frame.__new__(self)
        return self.instance

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        print id(self)
        if self.init:
            return
        self.init = 1

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Single Instance Frame")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()



########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Main Frame")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Open Frame")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.open_frame)
        self.Show()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def open_frame(self, event):
        frame = SingleInstanceFrame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I found another way to do this in addition to Mike's answer, so I figured I'd post it in case anyone needed it.

`SingleInstanceChecker` does in fact work for wx.Frames and wx.Panels. It works the same way as it would in an App.

Put this snipped of code in the `__init__` function of your Panel

```
self.instance = wx.SingleInstanceChecker(self.name)
```

Then, when instantiating your panel, call this:

```
    if panel.instance.IsAnotherRunning():
      wx.MessageBox("Another instance is running!", "ERROR")
      return
```

And it works exactly like you would expect it to.